# Как включить подсказки для переменных в python коде в VSCode или PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, visual-studio-code

Есть такой код:

```
import urllib.request

resp = urllib.request.urlopen('https://google.ru')

print(resp)
```

Пытаюсь в последней строек поставить точку после "resp" и нажимаю Ctrl+Space, чтобы посмотреть какие свойства и методы я могу использовать, но ничего нужного не появляется.

Скриншот из VSCode:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот из PyCharm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если написать print(resp.headers), то все прекрасно выполняется, но, как вы видите, свойства headers в подсказках автодополнения нет. Как это исправить?

Comment: Думаю, никак -- если открыть urlopen, то можно увидеть что в нем не указано какой тип ожидается, да и в его return'е вызывается `return opener.open(url, data, timeout)` а у метода `opener.open` тоже нет указания ожидаемого типа. Можно вызывать `print(dir(resp))` чтобы увидеть атрибуты, но это не совсем то что вам нужно

Comment: @gil9red, а нет ли, случайно, какой-то функции, чтобы IDE предвыполняла код и на основе этого сама понимала типы переменных, без отображения ошибок и подсказывала с автодополнением?

Comment: Не знаю, но было бы неплохо :) Спросите об этом у техподдержки либо дожидайтесь ответа от участников этого сайта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На стороне PyCharm нужно включить стабы для `urllib` из `typeshed`. Завел тикет, проголосовать можно здесь: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34668

А так можно руками взять [стабы из typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/bc8d68cd34a5657eecea0045c1e66c241cdef192/stdlib/3/urllib) и положить в `<pycharm_installation_folder>/helpers/typeshed/stdlib/3/`. После этого подсказки должны существенно поумнеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет, не знал о таких возможностях.
Может и для VS Code есть такой лайфхак?